# All samples are not executed in jmeter

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter

I am using ultimate thread group. I have 7 of them in the test plan. Each one of them has different samples. When I set thread count to 5, initial delay to 0, start up time to 30, hold load to 120 and shutdown time to 10, all the samples in the thread groups are executed in the result. When I increase the thread counts all the samples are not got in the result. Is there particular way to change the thread group settings, so that when I increase the thread count also, all samples are executed.

Answer (score 0):

All samples will execute if you increase thread number but you may be facing a load issue on your server and maybe having very long response time which you don't see if you didn't see connect or read timeouts.

Check jmeter.log file for errors and add timeouts to see if this could be the explanation.